# Click a line and open popup OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm loading a GPX file into my OL3 code. Now i'd like to whole line that the GPX makes to be clickable with some extra information. Now I can't for the life of me find a way to click the line drawn for the route. What listener can I use?

I don't want to click on the whole map but just the line.

I've tried attaching click/singleclick to `vector` to no avail.

Any ideas on how to do so?

My code:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var style = {

    'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#000',
            width: 3
        })
    }),
    'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#000',
            width: 3
        })
    })
};

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'kust.gpx',
        format: new ol.format.GPX()
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        return style[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the click on the map, and in the handler you check on wich feature you clicked. For example:

```
map.on('click', displayFeatureInfo); 

function displayFeatureInfo( evt ){
    //get pixel position of click event
    var pixel = evt.pixel;
    var features = [];
    //loop through all features under this pixel coordinate
    //and save them in array
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        features.push(feature)
    });

    //the top most feature
    var target = features[0];

    //...rest of code
    target.get('customProp')


}
```

**EDIT**

You can put some extra juice in your feature by inserting extra properies to the passed object. for example:

```
var myFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: ..., 
        labelPoint: ..,
        name:...,
        customProp1: ...,
        anothercustomProp: ...
      })
```

Comment: Clickevent seems to work. Now for step 2: Can I add custom data to my vector somehow which I can fetch in that function?

Comment: Never mind. Fixed by adding data via jQuery in the style method of Vector :)

Comment: @CaptainCarl added how to pass extra information inside features, faster and easier than jquery methods…

Comment: It is. Except that I don't manually make the feature since it's a GPX file I load. Any suggestion?

Comment: @CaptainCarl I´m not on my desk anymore, so I can't test it but have you tried to loop the features and add them? something like mySource.forEachFeature(function(_feature){ addProperties here… }));

Comment: I'll just stick with the jQuery method. It's perfectly fine and I need jQuery anyway ;-)

Comment: This whole concept crumbles when I add a second route/Vector by the way. It seems that the vector isn't instantiated properly. Colors, data etc. are all duplicated. Choosing the first feature is not a working solution either.

Comment: it doesnt need to be the first, you can add a property in the feature like, let's say "type" and in the loop you filter the others out. Do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: I use actual GPX files so not really, no. A type isn't enough of a identification though. I have a variable number of GPX files which all have to be displayed on one map. A click should open a popup with its title. The dataset I made works fine so that's good. It's just that you can't click A line and it's identified as route X.